# How to calculate UITableViewCell Height when have more UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

We use systemLayoutSizeFitting to calculate UITableViewCell`s height when number of UILabel less than 2, like this: 
[image: single image]

How to calculate Cell Height when have more UILabel like this?
[image]

Comment: post your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your 2nd image it looks like you haven't set constraints correctly for vertical direction (red color).

can i ask why you need height?

if it's for heightForRowAtIndexPath: i'd suggest to use selfsizing cells? then you don't need to calculate height explicitly.

```
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

 //remove delegate call
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {}
```

Comment: if there have only one UILabel , like 1nd image , I can get constraints correctly for vertical direction,then change label.text ,caculate cellHeight easy from systemLayoutSizeFitting like this :
let cell = TableViewCell()
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height + 1
    }
but like 2nd image,I want use systemLayoutSizeFitting to caculate cellHeight like only one label ,i dont know how to set constraints correctly for vertical direction

Comment: Constraints: depends on what you're trying to achieve, if you want the first label height to be static and not following content size then try adding a height constraint to top label. alternative: set content hugging priority down of top label or content compression resistancy priority down for bottom label

Comment: do you use systemLayoutSizeFitting to caculate dynamic UITableViewCell`s height?

Comment: I have know the mean of you answer，Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this question, use label's `Content Hugging Priority` attribute to solve

[image]

Comment: Yeah ,tim have tell me